# What is the antonym for ticklish?

Tags: grammar

> I am very ticklish

What is the antonym for ticklish?

Is it "I am not ticklish"?

Comment: Hipposensitive? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic way to say that one is not ticklish: *I'm not ticklish*.

Words ending in the suffix -ish (e.g. skittish, bookish, snobbish, boorish, roguish, etc).

express a tendency to have, to some degree, the trait found in the word's stem; as tendencies, these words don't have antonyms.

Comment: The op asks for the antonym of the word. Not which way it is idiomatic. The op is aware of an idiomatic way.

Comment: This site is about learning English, so this is the right answer.

Comment: I agree that many _-ish_ words don't have antonyms. However, some do. Antonyms for _boorish_, for example, could include _polite_ and _refined_; an antonym for _skittish_ might be _relaxed_, depending on the context. However, in the case of _ticklish_, I agree that the best "antonym" for casual conversation would be **not ticklish**.

Comment: *polite* and *boorish* connote roughly opposite ideas but they are not "pure" antonyms like hot/cold, fast/slow, wide/narrow, tall/short. I would make a distinction between opposite denotations and roughly opposite connotations.

Comment: @TRomano - Here's another problem with "pure" antonyms (whether the words end with *-ish* or not): many words are multifaceted, and therefore have many antonyms, be they denotations or connotations. We could say the opposite of _short_ is _long_, for example (as opposed to _tall_); we could say the opposite of _hot_ is _mild_ (instead of _cold_); and we could have picked _feast_ as an antonym of _fast_, if we treated _fast_ as a verb. It's tricky stuff, but that's what makes ELL fun – and why some people bristle when they hear that ELL questions are "basic." Quite the opposite, sometimes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the adjective *ticklish* is used for two reasons. When referred to a person, it means that the person is too [sensitive when they are tickled](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ticklish) and when referred to a problem or situation, it denotes [difficulties](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ticklish).

You clarified that the context is human.

My medical brain has an answer to this:

> [hyposensitive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hyposensitive) -*Less than the normal ability to respond to stimuli.*

[OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hyposensitivity) too have this definition.

> Hey, don't touch me. I'm very ticklish ~ Oh yeah? Try hard on me, I'm *hyposensitive*

We often describe a patient with less response to the stimuli quite opposite to someone who is *ticklish*.

[I think the words with prefix *hypo-* and *hyper-* are no longer medical terms as they are used broadly by normal public].

Comment: _Is there a [doctor](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IsThereADoctorInTheHouse) in the house_? Bravo!

Answer (score -3):

Thick-skinned is the antonym I found for ticklish.

Comment: Not even close. Thick-skinned is 'impervious to ridicule or criticism' unless you are actually talking about an elephant or hippo. If the OP means 'laughs when prodded under the armpits', then afaik, it has no antonym, so 'not ticklish' would be correct.

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin - if you disagree with us, there's plenty of room in your answer to elaborate and prove us both wrong. Dig up a few example usages where _thick-skinned_ means "not ticklish," and cite them here, or at least tell us where you "found" this antonym. (There's a reason SE has a minimum character count for answers, but no maximum – answers are expected to more than quick opinions.)

Comment: @J.R. Technically, I think [answers are limited to 30,000 characters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14142/215040)―though it's a very generous limit that few users are ever likely to run into.